# Crawling twitter data, check for new tweets?

Tags: twitter

i'm crawling the twitter stream for a particular hashtag. 
my search query url is: http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=sample%20query&rpp=100&result_type=recent
After every calls, i get the maximum tweet id and append "since_id=MAXID" before making the next call.
The trouble with this approach is, there may be no new tweets created between two calls, and the new call returns an empty array. This leads to wasted calls which is not feasible because of the Rate limit.
What is the best way to get around this?
Thanks!